# Different pixel values loading an image from stream in python2 and python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I'm migrating some code from python2 to python3 which loads an image from a bytes stream. I need the resulting image to have the exact same values in all its pixels. However with the implementation below both images differ in some pixels on some values of intensity.

Here is the python 2.7 implementation:

```py
from PIL import Image
from cStringIO import StringIO
import requests

img_url = "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508921912186-1d1a45ebb3c1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8cGhvdG98ZW58MHx8MHx8&w=1000&q=80"
response = requests.get(img_url)
bytes_data = response.content
stream = StringIO(bytes_data)
img = Image.open(stream)
```

And here is the python3.8 implementation:

```py
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
import requests

img_url = "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508921912186-1d1a45ebb3c1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8cGhvdG98ZW58MHx8MHx8&w=1000&q=80"
response = requests.get(img_url)
bytes_data = response.content
stream = BytesIO(bytes_data)
img = Image.open(stream)
```

- <s>In both virtual environments I'm using the same version of PIL (2.8.2) to make sure the differences don't come from there.</s> (Edit 1)
- The requests response returns the same, `bytes_data` is exactly the same bytes string in both implementations.

<s>My guess is that the pixel differences come from the stream object, but I don't know much about the topic.</s> (Edit 1)

**Edit 1:** If the PIL version is the same (2.8.2) in both python2.7 and python3.8 the results are the same. This would point out that the difference comes from the PIL version rather than the python version.

**Edit 2:** The loaded JPGS start differing at PIL version 9.0.0

Comment: Your PIL version sounds wrong, or prehistoric - I am on v8.4

Comment: It is a very old legacy code I'm migrating, hehe so it is indeed prehistoric. The code is from 2016 but I it was not up to date back then either.

Answer (score 1):

That stream is JPEG data. JPEG is lossy and implementations of JPEG codecs are permitted to make different approximations and trade-offs in order to prefer performance or speed or compression ratio. Likewise, different versions of the same library are allowed to do so.

My guess would be that you have a different JPEG library version between the 2 environments. You should be able to check with:

```
python3 -m PIL | grep -i JPEG
```

and

```
python2.7 -m PIL | grep -I JPEG
```

---

Other ways to see the PIL version:

```
import PIL
print(PIL.__version__)
```

Or:

```
import PIL
print(dir(PIL))
```

Or from your shell outside your Python interpreter:

```
pip3 show Pillow

Name: Pillow
Version: 8.4.0
Summary: Python Imaging Library (Fork)
Home-page: https://python-pillow.org
Author: Alex Clark (PIL Fork Author)
Author-email: aclark@python-pillow.org
License: HPND
Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by: CairoSVG, imageio, matplotlib
```

Comment: I made a mistake, the python3.8 env had the PIL version 9.0 instead of 2.8.2. When setting both to 2.8.2 the output is the same. This means that the differences come from the PIL version and not the python 2.7 vs 3.8.  I edited the question.

I was no able to get the JPEG library version from PIL v2.8.2, I get this error: `No module named PIL.__main__; 'PIL' is a package and cannot be directly executed
`

Comment: I added some other ways to see versions.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I managed to track down the differences to PIL 9.0.0, the previous version 8.4.0 yields the same results as the old 2.8.2.

From the [changelog](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/main/CHANGES.rst#900-2022-01-02) I'm not sure what it's the root cause of the differences.